# How do I evenly space items within nested CSS Grid Columns?

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/tnr24g6j/5/

In a simple recreation of Google.com I'm trying to space out the top navigation bar so that about, store, Gmail, and Images are in their own container. I think `justify-items:center;` on the container class is causing the issue but I can't fix it.

Here is an image example of what I'm trying to get to happen: https://ibb.co/QXzv5vd.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">

<div class = "nav-container">
<nav class = "nav-container-grid">
<a class = "nested-a">About</a>
<a class = "nested-b">Store</a>
<a class = "nested-c">Gmail</a>
<a class = "nested-d">Images</a>
</nav>
</div>

<div id ="image-container">
<img src='https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png' alt='Google'>
</div>

<div class="button-container">
<button>Google Search</button>
<button>I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
</div>

<div class="search-container">
<input type="search" placeholder="Search">
</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
}
.nav-container {
  grid-row: 1;
}

.nav-container-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.nav-container-grid a {
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    align-content: right;
}

.image-container {
  grid-row: 2; 
}
.search-container {
  grid-row: 3;
}

.button-container {
  grid-row: 4;
}

.nested-a {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}
.nested-b{
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}
.nested-c{
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}
.nested-d{
  grid-column-start:4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set your `.nav-container-grid` to be split into 4 equal columns which is correct, and it is working... the problem is that it is getting 4 equal columns of `nav-container`, but as you have noticed, when you apply `justify-items:center`, the columns are resized to fit the content of the largest column.

To fix this, you can make the `.nav-container-grid`'s parent 100% width:

```
.nav-container { grid-row: 1; width: 100%; }
```

**Working Example:**

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 1fr 1fr;
  justify-items: center;
}

.nav-container {
  grid-row: 1;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-container-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.nav-container-grid a {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  align-content: right;
}

.image-container {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.search-container {
  grid-row: 3;
}

.button-container {
  grid-row: 4;
}

.nested-a {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.nested-b {
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.nested-c {
  grid-column-start: 3;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}

.nested-d {
  grid-column-start: 4;
  grid-row-start: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="nav-container">
    <nav class="nav-container-grid">
      <a class="nested-a">About</a>
      <a class="nested-b">Store</a>
      <a class="nested-c">Gmail</a>
      <a class="nested-d">Images</a>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div id="image-container">
    <img src='https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png' alt='Google'>
  </div>

  <div class="button-container">
    <button>Google Search</button>
    <button>I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
  </div>

  <div class="search-container">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search">
  </div>

</div>
```